# Regex for starting a string with two special characters

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to write a regular expression to force the user to fill an input with a 10 digit character that should start with 09. Like the followings:

```
0912345678
0968765432
.
.
.
```

I wrote th following to check the length:

```
[StringLength(10)]
[MinLength(10)]
```

Now I dont know how to check that its started with 09.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: you could try this `^09[0-9]{8}$` regex also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^09\d{8}$
```

Explanation:

- `^` - Beginning of the string
- `09` - Matches the digits `09` literally
- `\d{8}` - Matches *exactly* 8 digits
- `$` - End of the string

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/zF1jI5)**